# jquery mobile viewswitcher & opera mobile emulator

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I started experimenting with jquery mobile's viewswitcher to add a link to a mobile page so that a tablet user would have the option of viewing the desktop version of my asp.net mvc site.  But after the first time I clicked the 'view desktop' link on the mobile page opera mobile emulator will now only display my site in desktop, it won't go back to the normal mobile pages no matter what.  I've removed the viewswitcher code from my project, and tried loading an old version of my code prior to using jquery mobile viewswitcher but opera mobile still will only show the desktop version from localhost.  Does IIS express save some configuration that permanently got switched for localhost to only show in desktop mode regardless of the user agent?  I tried uninstalling / reinstalling opera mobile emulator.  Opera mobile emulator does show the correct mobile page if I view the site live from a web server. Please advise.  Thank you.

Comment: I believe the view switcher works by setting a persistent cookie in the browser. In an Opera Mobile Emulator browser window go to Settings -> Privacy and select Clear Cookies.

Comment: Not only did that fix the problem but the answer came from THE Scott Allen?!  You're a gentleman and a scholar.  Fantastic, thank you!